# aggregated.css is not updated when a css file is modified (mean.io module)

Tags: node.js, mean.io

I've created a mean.io module within a new project. All the good stuff is there: grunt (+plugins, sass among them). grunt-sass is auto-generating a css file under

```
packages/myModule/public/assets/css/mystyle.css
```

To include it in the aggregated css, in app.js I added

```
myModule.aggregateAsset('css', 'mystyle.css');
```

When I spin up the server (using grunt in NODE_ENV=dev) I see that the file content has being correctly aggregated together with the default angular css into 'aggregate.css'.

The problem is: when the dev server is already up and css file is modified, the app reloads - but the aggregated css is not updated. I've inspected the http GET for aggregate.css on the browser end and see it still has the older settings. The only way I found to get the new css in was to ctrl+c and restart the server.

Why is aggregated.css not reflecting the new css content when the page refreshes?

Comment: Not yet. I've opened a ticket on the mean.io github project: https://github.com/linnovate/mean/issues/683 Looks like others are also seeing this behavior

Comment: I've been seeing this since I started using mean.io a couple weeks ago. I haven't found a workaround other than restarting the server. Definitely through me for a loop because grunt says it say and saved the new css changes, and the web dev tools say it loaded the resource.